# Encoding a number with a suffix or prefix in a compact way

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, uniqueidentifier

Let's say I have 6 digits order ids:

```
000000
000001
000003
...
000020
...
999999
```

And assume each of these come from a different node in a distributed system and I would like to encode the node id into the order.
The easiest way to do this would be to simply reserve the first 2 digits for the node id like this:

```
010000 - second node
020001 - third node
010003 - second node again
150004 - 16th node
...
```

This works sort of fine, but since I know for sure I'm only expecting a small number of nodes (let's say 16) I'm losing lots of possible ids limiting myself to basically 10^4 instead of 10^6. Is there a smart way to encode the 15 unique nodes without limiting the possible numbers? Ideally, I would have `10^6 - 15` possibilities.

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that won't equally distribute a range to each node id. I'm looking for a way to encode the node id in an already existing unique id, without losing (ideally) more that the number of nodes of possibilities.

EDIT2: The reason for which this has to be the string representation of a 6 digit number is because the API I'm working with requires this. There's no way around it, unfortunately.

Comment: If you think on bits instead of digits, you can encode 15 nodes with 4 bits.

Comment: Are you storing or displaying these numbers as 6-digit decimal numbers at any point? Because a 32-bit integer needed to store integers up to 999999 has 12 unused bits that you could use to store additional information.

Comment: @m69 As stupid as it might sound, some API designer decided 6 digits is more than enough for this so I actually have to send the rep of a 6 *digit* number as a string. So no, I can't use any remaining bits, unfortunately :(

Comment: @juvian That I tried. Problem is, the nearest representation of a 6 digit number is 2^20. So, 20 bits. However, it slightly goes above in the 7 digit area. I'm trying to figure out a way to limit it right now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying in the comments (I'd put the bit about the API design in the question) - that makes the challenge more interesting!

Comment: @גלעד ברקן Thanks, good idea!

Comment: (Aside: there is no value in posting in-question messages to ask why someone downvoted. If they did not already declare why they did so, they will have long gone, so the only effect of adding this is to clutter a post with material that is not useful. Put this in the comments if you have to, but it probably won't be answered there either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm losing lots of possible ids limiting myself to basically 10^4 instead of 10^6.

We still have `10^4 * 16` ids **in total**.

> Is there a smart way to encode the 15 unique nodes without limiting the possible numbers?

This problem is similar to the [distributed hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) keyspace partitioning. The best known solution for the problem is to create lots of virtual nodes, divide the keyspace among those virtual nodes and then assign those virtual nodes to physical in a particular manner (round-robin, random, on demand etc).

The easiest way to implement keyspace partition is to make sure each node generates such an id, that:

```
vnode_id = order_id % total_number_of_vnodes
```

For example, if we have just 3 vnodes [0, 1, 2] then:

```
vnode 0 must generate ids: 0, 3, 6, 9...
vnode 1 must generate ids: 1, 4, 7, 10...
vnode 2 must generate ids: 2, 5, 7, 11...
```

If we have 7 vnodes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] then:

```
vnode 0 must generate ids: 0, 7, 14, 21... 
vnode 1 must generate ids: 1, 8, 15, 22... 
vnode 2 must generate ids: 2, 9, 16, 23... 
...
vnode 6 must generate ids: 6, 13, 20, 27...
```

Then all physical nodes must map to the virtual in the known and common way, for example 1:1 mapping:

```
physical node 0 takes vnode 0
physical node 1 takes vnode 1
physical node 2 takes vnode 2
```

on demand mapping:

```
physical node 0 takes vnode 0, 3, 7 (many orders)
physical node 1 takes vnode 1, 4 (less orders)
physical node 2 takes vnode 2 (no orders)
```

I hope you grasp the idea.

> Ideally, I would have 10^6 - 15 possibilities.

Unfortunately, it is not possible. Consider this: we have a 10^6 of possible ids and 15 different nodes each generating an *unique* id.

Basically, this means that one way or another we are dividing our ids among nodes, i.e. each node gets in average `10^6 / 15`, which is much less than desirable `10^6 - 15`.

Using the method described above we still have `10^6` ids in total, but they will be partitioned among vnodes which in turn will be mapped to physical nodes. That is the best practical solution for your problem AFAIK.

> I'm looking for a solution that won't equally distribute a range to each node id. I'm looking for a way to encode the node id in an already existing unique id, without losing (ideally) more that the number of nodes of possibilities.

Do not expect a miracle. There are might be lots of other tricks worth trying.

For example, if Server and all Clients know that the next order id must be 235, but say Client 5 generates order id 240 (235 + 5) and send it to Server.

Server expects order id 235, but receive order id 240. So now Server knows that this order comes form Client 5 (240 - 235).

Or we can try to use another field to store client id. For instance if you have a time filed (HH:MM.SS), we might use seconds to store Client id.

Just some examples, I guess you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

Let `n` be the number represented by the first 2 digits of the 6 digit input. Assuming you have 16 nodes we can do:

```
nodeId = n % 16
```

Also:

```
highDigit = n / 16
```

Where `/` represents integer division. For 16 nodes, highDigit = [0..6]

If `m` is the number represented by the last 4 digits of the input then we can recover the original order id by:

```
orderId = highDigit*10^5 + m
```

With this scheme, and 16 nodes, you can represent 6*10^5 + 10^4 order ids.

Answer (score 0):

You could split up the 10^6 possible IDs into close-to-equal chunks where the beginning index of each chunk is equal to 10^6 divided by the number of chunks, round down, times the chunk index, and the chunk size is 10^6 divided by the number of chunks, round down. In your example there are sixteen chunks:

```
10^6 / 16 = 62,500
chunk1:  [     0,   62500)
chunk2:  [ 62500,  125000)
chunk3:  [125000,  187500)
chunk4:  [187500,  250000)
chunk5:  [250000,  312500)
chunk6:  [312500,  375000)
chunk7:  [375000,  437500)
chunk8:  [437500,  500000)
chunk9:  [500000,  562500)
chunk10: [562500,  625000)
chunk11: [625000,  687500)
chunk12: [687500,  750000)
chunk13: [750000,  812500)
chunk14: [812500,  875000)
chunk15: [875000,  937500)
chunk16: [937500, 1000000)
```

To compute a global ID from a local ID on node X, calculate 62500 * X + local ID. To determine the node and local ID from a node calculate node = global ID / 62500 round down and local ID = global ID mod 62500.

Doing this you get to use basically all of the available indices up to a rounding error. Division and modulus on integers should be relatively quick compared to I/O between nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've chosen to use digits (rather than bits, where we could compact this entire exercise into a 32-bit number), here's one way to encode node ids. Perhaps others can come up with some more ideas.

Extend the digit alphabet up to `J`. Imagine the bits of the node's ID are distributed over the six digits. For each set bit, map the decimal digit of the order ID to a letter:

```
0 -> A
1 -> B
2 -> C
...
9 -> J
```

For example:

```
{759243, 5} -> 759C4D
```

Now you can encode all 10^6 order IDs together with a 6-bit node ID.

Comment: That would work. In a way similar to encoding base 16. But unfortunately the final result should be a 6 *digit* string (no letters). However, we can use bits as well, as long as the result is a 6 digit unique string (e.g. using the first 4 or even 8 bits is an  idea played around with, but got stuck because the closest rep of a 6 digits number is 2^20, but some of the values(a bit above 10^7) are 7 digits (I managed to do a working algorithm for 7 digits only)

Comment: @ValentinRadu How are the "digits" represented? Why the constraint on which characters we choose? (each decimal digit is usually part of an ASCII character base represented in one byte)

Comment: @ValentinRadu what I (and others) are getting at is a 32-bit number can store all relevant information and still allow you to represent the 6 *digit* string whenever you wanted to "display" it as such.

Comment: This constraint is out of my control. The guy who designed the API decided: 6 digit only string: (e.g. 000338, 999223, etc). Adding a character will return an error from the API. I know it's a stupid constraint, but it's there.